# remove redundant code in method

Tags: javascript, jquery, mapreduce, ternary-operator

Im using the following code which works but after reading about JS(im fairly new) I've noticed of 3 things.

1. using return at the beginning of the method
2. using `ternary` condition (not sure how to use it in this case)
3. using `reduce` (not sure about this but maybe instead of the forEach)

is it possible to use it in the following code?

```
 get: function(document, oData) {
        var self = this;
        var oInnerHTML;
        if (oData) {
            var oParsedHTML = this._parseHtml(document);
            oInnerHTML = oParsedHTML;
            oData.forEach(function(configEntry) {
                oInnerHTML = self._routeExtentionTypes(configEntry, oInnerHTML);
            });
            oInnerHTML = this._convertBackToHtml(oInnerHTML);
        } else {
            oInnerHTML = document;
        }
         return oInnerHTML
    }
```

**What the code is doing is**

> 1. getting HtmlString and parse it
> 2. extend it according to the cofigEntry and the original HTML
> 3. when the config entry was done it convert back to HTML

Comment: what is `self._routeExtentionTypes(configEntry, oInnerHTML);` doing?

Comment: @NinaScholz - This return an extended HTML , the input is configEntry which is instance of array of objects and The oInnerHTML is the original html which I send and get back extended HTML

Comment: @NinaScholz - does it answer your question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you can try that with [`Array#reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

Basically the reduce is doing what you want. It takes a start value and iterates an array and returns some value, as desired.

The former code

```
var oParsedHTML = this._parseHtml(document);
    oInnerHTML = oParsedHTML;
oData.forEach(function(configEntry) {
    oInnerHTML = self._routeExtentionTypes(configEntry, oInnerHTML);
});
```

convertes to

```
this._convertBackToHtml(oData.reduce(function (r, configEntry) {
    return self._routeExtentionTypes(configEntry, r);
}, this._parseHtml(document))) :
```

because the start value is now `this._parseHtml(document)` without the need of an additional variable and the return value becomes the new input value for the next iteration.

```
get: function (document, oData) {
    var self = this;
    return oData ?
        this._convertBackToHtml(oData.reduce(function (r, configEntry) {
            return self._routeExtentionTypes(configEntry, r);
        }, this._parseHtml(document))) :
        document;
}
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try it now , btw I update the question with more info regard what the code is doing...

Comment: Thanks it seems that this is works 1+! im now checking it further ,two question :) 1. if I remove the ternary how the code look like (a bit diffucult to understand )2. can you please explain a bit about your code.

Comment: the skip the ternary, if you are sure, that `oData` is always thruthy, then return `this._convertBackToHtml(oData.reduce(function (r, configEntry) {
            return self._routeExtentionTypes(configEntry, r);
        }, this._parseHtml(document)));`

Answer (score 1):

**using return at the beginning of the method**

Use return when your object is get ready with desired value. It is good practice to return at the earliest opportunity. That way the least amount of code gets executed and evaluated.

In above example "**oInnerHTML**" variable get ready with value based certain conditions satisfied, so in this case you can return it as soon as the object/variable get ready with value.

**using ternary condition**

The ternary operator is common when you're assigning a value to a variable based on a simple condition or you are making multiple decisions with very brief outcomes. e.g

```
x ? y: z
```

In above example the ternary operator could be use as below: (Please execute the code and double check)

```
get: function(document, oData) {
  var self = this;      
  return (oData) ? document : get_oInnerHTML(oData);
}      

function get_oInnerHTML (oData){
  var oInnerHTML;
  oData.forEach(function(configEntry) { oInnerHTML = self._routeExtentionTypes(configEntry, this._parseHtml(document)); });
  return oInnerHTML;
}
```

Above code used a function in ternary conditions. As there are many lines which needs to execute inside condition so I created separated function for it and use in condition.

**using reduce**

The reduce() method applies a function against an accumulator and each value of the array (from left-to-right) to reduce it to a single value.

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4].reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue, currentIndex, array) { return previousValue + currentValue; });
```